# Maven multi module build issue

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get this sample maven multi-module project (from the maven book) to build and install but it says that the dependent sibling is not available.

[image]

I first try to get compile and install the weather-model and it works fine.

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/johne/IdeaProjects/WeatherApp/weather-web/weather-model/target/weather-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/johne/.m2/repository/com/testcom/weather-model/1.0-SNAPSHOT/weather-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/johne/IdeaProjects/WeatherApp/weather-web/weather-model/pom.xml to /Users/johne/.m2/repository/com/testcom/weather-model/1.0-SNAPSHOT/weather-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

But when I try `mvn install` from weather-web directory it fails.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.testcom:weather-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Weather Web POM .................................... SUCCESS [  9.215 s]
[INFO] Weather App Model .................................. SUCCESS [  0.564 s]
[INFO] Weather App Persistence ............................ FAILURE [  0.028 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.933 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-24T10:48:28+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project weather-persist: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.testcom:weather-persist:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.testcom:weather-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

WeatherWeb pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>weatherapp</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.testcom</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>weather-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <modules>
        <module>weather-model</module>
        <module>weather-persist</module>
    </modules>

    <name>Weather Web POM</name>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Weather Persistence pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>weather-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.testcom</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>weather-persist</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Weather App Persistence</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.testcom</groupId>
            <artifactId>weather-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Weather model pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>weather-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.testcom</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>weather-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Weather App Model</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Please add weather-model `pom.xml`

Comment: @talex added the weather-model's pom.

Comment: @John Could not find artifact com.testcom:weather-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT , Build weather-model's pom independently and check whether it is getting published in .m2, and then build weather-persist or weather-web.

Comment: @John , which maven version you are using, I tried to reproduce the issue but failed, It is working fine.

Comment: I can read a warning above: [WARNING] The POM for com.testcom:weather-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: @MohitSharma you ran `mvn install` ? and did you run it at parent level?
If you notice I had run the weather model independently. I have added the logs also.

Comment: @John , I ran mvn clean install and Yes on parent.

Comment: I suggest to remove `/Users/johne/.m2/repository/com/testcom` and run maven again.

Comment: yes. I tried that and I ran mvn clean install on parent. @MohitSharma

Comment: Update your maven , check the artifact weather model in local mvn repo

Comment: I'm using maven 3.5. and model jar is there in the local repository folder.

Comment: [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Weather Web POM .................................... SUCCESS [  0.453 s]
[INFO] Weather App Model .................................. SUCCESS [  1.100 s]
[INFO] Weather App Persistence ............................ SUCCESS [  0.120 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.790 s

Comment: @MohitSharma could you checkout it from https://github.com/john77eipe/WeatherApp and try. Because I tried the whole thing in a new Docker container and still the same error.

Comment: @John issue is persistence pom, spelling mistake , group Id is wrong for model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your dependency inclusion. I took your github code and changed the persistence pom.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.siriuscom</groupId>
        <artifactId>weather-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

siruscom changed to siriuscom and It Works like a charm, 
In the question you posted different group Id, It is also working.

Always copy-paste, Never manually type.

Comment: Can't believe this. lol. Ya I'm going to print "Always copy-paste, Never Manually Type" on my t-shirt :-P